# wrap rules with selector conditionally

Tags: sass

What I'm trying to do is a mixin with a optional parameter to include or not a selector around rules. Here is the behavior expected :

```
@include smth(true)  => .class{ color:blue }
@include smth(false) => color: blue
```

I tried something like this :

```
@mixin smth($selector:true){
   @if $selector {
      .class{
   }

   color: blue;

   @if $selector{
       }
   }
}
```

Obviously brackets inside the @if directive are the problem. So I tried putting the content of the @if under double quote `".class{"`and using interpolation `#{".class{"}` (with and without the escape character `\`} so it won't interfere but nothings work.
To be short I don't want sass to process content of the @if but just "put it as it is".

**UPDATE**

From cimmanon answer I managed to create a more general mixin :

```
@mixin conditional-wrap($condition, $selector){
  @if $condition{
    #{$selector}{
        @content
    }
  }
  @else{
    @content
  }
}
```

And so we can now do :

```
@mixin smth($selector:true){
  @include conditional-wrap($selector, '.class'){
      color: blue;
  }
}
```

Comment: Voting to close as typographical error (hint: you can't have more opening curly braces than you have closing curly braces).

Comment: do you mean inside the same @if directive ? because otherwise there isn't.

Comment: Then your nesting is messed up, you need to find an editor that will show matching curly braces.

Answer (score 2):

Sass is a *scripting language*.  Curly braces are part of the SCSS syntax (just like any other language that uses curly braces:  JavaScript, PHP, C/C++ etc.), Sass doesn't just "put it as it is".  The SASS (indented) syntax doesn't use curly braces at all.  The parsers for each syntax differs, but the internal representation of the selectors and their properties is the same, and so is the way those structures are output when generating a CSS file:  the curly braces are inserted as appropriate according to the output style.  In short, what you're trying to write is impossible.

Sass doesn't care how you indent your code using the SCSS syntax, it only cares about matching curly braces.  As a result, your mixin is being interpreted like this:

```
@mixin smth($selector: true) {
   @if $selector {
       .class {

       }

       color: blue;

       @if $selector {

       }
   }
}
```

What you *can* do instead is change your logic.

```
@mixin smth($selector: true) {
    @at-root #{if($selector, selector-nest(&, '.class'), &)} {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

For Sass version 3.3 or older:

```
@mixin foo {
    color: blue;
}

@mixin smth($selector: true) {
    @if $selector {
        .class {
            @include foo;
        }
    } @else {
        @include foo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thks for the explanation. Your second solution is what I ended up doing at first but then I realised I had better use 2 mixin ```smth``` and ```smthSelector``` rather than using just one with a parameter. First solution looks promising, I'll look for information about ```@at-root``` and ```selector-nest```

Comment: Your first solution does not work for me, the whole point of doing this is to avoid duplication of same selector on the final css. Because of ```@at-root``` when ```$selector``` is false we will have same selector twice.

Comment: @Ghetolay "Does not work" is a useless description of the problem.  Sassmeister says it works fine:  http://sassmeister.com/gist/25ebc0956f781ff6746d

Comment: I didn't just said 'it didn't work' I've explained (or at least tried to) why it isn't working *for me*. Here is a fork of your sassmeister demonstrating the case I tried to explain : http://sassmeister.com/gist/d3d2a4a7cd5940cb5109